# How to add delay to specific part of loop

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the blue squares to move randomly every few seconds. My main problem is I can't create a delay with a sleep or pygame wait without shutting down the entire loop for a few moments. If I put it in a separate loop then one of the loops won't fire. What else can I do?

Code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
# colors
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

win = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 400))

x = 0
y = 350
width = 50
height = 50
run = True
while run:

    if randx == 1:
        randx = 0
    elif randx == 2:
        randx = 50
    elif randx == 3:
        randx = 100
    elif randx == 4:
        randx = 150
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # player #####
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        # left arrow
        x -= 50
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        # right arrow
        x += 50
    # looping screen
    if x >= 200:
        x = 0
    if x < 0:
        x = 150
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
            accel_x = 0
            accel_y = 0

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, BLUE,(randx, 0, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the time, which means you can create a timer by

```
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

while run:
    ...
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - start_time > 1000 #if if has been 1 second (1000 millaseconds)
       #move squares
       start_time = now #reset timer
```

Answer (score 0):

For such problems, you need to utilize the power of `multithreading`. Your current program is executing in a single flow. Therefore, when you call `sleep`, this whole program is blocked. `Multithreading` can help you break your program in seperate flows:

> A thread is a separate flow of execution. This means that your program will have two things happening at once.

You can read [this article](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) to understand `multithreading`.